# find whether attachment is present in the mail using android gmail api

Tags: android, gmail, gmail-imap

I have googled a lot to find whether it is possible to get the mail attachment information from android gmail api. Using android gmail api its able to get the inbox message details but I am not sure whether its able to get the mail attachment information. I found google developers docs code providing access to the gmail inbox messages count, but could not find any code accessing mail attachment information. Please help me to get the mail attachment information using android gmail api. Thanks in advance